# Yii2 create data row works but update doesn't

Tags: php, yii2

I saw red some answers on similar questions but still can't understand where is my problem. I have a `_form.php` which is used when data row is created and updated аlso. When i create data row it is OK but when it redirects me to `return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);` but the data is not updated. Tried to `var_dump($model->getErrors())` (as I saw in the answers of another question) but it returns me and empty `array`.
These are my files: 
Controller action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $settings = new Settings();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $languages = Lang::find()->all();
            foreach ($languages as $language) {
                if ($language->default != 1) {

                    $names = 'names_' . $language->url;
                    $varNames = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$names);
                    $model->$names = $varNames;

                    $review = 'review_' . $language->url;
                    $varReview = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$review);
                    $model->$review = $varReview;

                    $metaDesc = 'meta_desc_' . $language->url;
                    $varMetaDesc = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$metaDesc);
                    $model->$metaDesc = $varMetaDesc;

                    $url = 'url_' . $language->url;
                    $varUrl = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$url);
                    $model->$url = $varUrl;

                    $cBirth = 'country_birth_' . $language->url;
                    $varcBirth = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$cBirth);
                    $model->$cBirth = $varcBirth;
                }
                else
                {
                    $model->names = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->names);
                    $model->review = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->review);
                    $model->meta_desc = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->meta_desc);
                    $model->url= Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->url);
                    $model->country_birth = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->country_birth);
                }
            }

            //записване на изображенията + thumb
            if (isset($_POST["Author"]["imageFiles"]) and ! empty($_POST["Author"]["imageFiles"])) {

                $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
                if (isset($model->imageFiles) and count($model->imageFiles) > 0) {
                    foreach ($model->imageFiles as $key => $file) {
                        $parseProdTitle = MakeURL::parseImageName($model->names.'_'.$model->id);
                        $fileName = $parseProdTitle . '_' . $model->id . '.' . $file->extension;
                        $fileName = Yii::$app->translate->cyr_to_lat($fileName);
                        $model->filename = $fileName;
                        $model->save(false);
                        $pic = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . '/authors/thumb-270/' . $fileName;
                        $pic2 = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . '/authors/' . $fileName;
                        $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . '/authors/' . $fileName);
                        $image = file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . '/authors/' . $fileName);
                        file_put_contents($pic, $image);
                        $model->resizeImg($pic);
                        $settings->compress($pic, $pic, 90);
                        $settings->compress($pic2, $pic2, 90);
                    }
                }
            }

           if($model->update()){
               var_dump(1);die;
           }else{
               var_dump($model->getErrors());die;// it dumps here but it returns an empty array
           }

           if($model->validate()){
               var_dump(1);die;// it dumps here so validate is ok ( I guess )
           }else{
               var_dump($model->getErrors());die;
           }


            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And my model:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualBehavior;
use omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualQuery;
use kartik\helpers\Html;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "author".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $active
 * @property string $filename
 * @property integer $sort
 * @property data $birthday
 *
 * @property AuthorLang[] $authorLangs
 */
class Author extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $imageFiles;
    private $languages = array();

    public function __construct() {
        foreach(Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $langArr){
            $langParam = new Lang;
            $langParam->id = $langArr['id'];
            $langParam->url = $langArr['url'];
            $langParam->local = $langArr['local'];
            $langParam->name = $langArr['name'];
            $langParam->default = $langArr['default'];
            $langParam->active = $langArr['active'];
            $this->languages[] = $langParam;
        }
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function find()
    {
        return new MultilingualQuery(get_called_class());
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $languagesArray = [];
        foreach($this->languages as $language){
            if($language->default){
                $defLang = $language->url;
            }
            $languagesArray[$language->local] = $language->name;
        }

        return [
            'ml' => [
                'class' => MultilingualBehavior::className(),
                'languages' => $languagesArray,
                //'languageField' => 'language',
                //'localizedPrefix' => '',
                //'requireTranslations' => false',
                //'dynamicLangClass' => true',
                //'langClassName' => PostLang::className(), // or namespace/for/a/class/PostLang
                'defaultLanguage' => $defLang,
                'langForeignKey' => 'author_id',
                'tableName' => "{{%authorLang}}",
                'attributes' => [
                    'names',
                    'review',
                    'meta_desc',
                    'url',
                    'country_birth',
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'author';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $required = ['names', 'review', 'meta_desc', 'url', 'birthday', 'country_birth'];

        $this->checkLanguage([$required]);

        return [
            [['active', 'sort'], 'required'],
            [$required, 'required'],
            ['names', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['country_birth', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['review', 'string'],
            ['meta_desc', 'string', 'max' => 170],
            ['url', 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['active', 'sort'], 'integer'],
            [['filename'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    protected function checkLanguage($megaArr = [])
    {
        foreach ($this->languages as $language)
        {
            if($language->default != 1)
            {
                foreach ($megaArr as $fields)
                {
                    foreach ($fields as $field)
                    {
                        $field .= '_' . $language->url;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function changeActiveForm() {
        $active = "";
        if ($this->active == 1) {
            $active = 'checked="checked"';
        }
        return '<label class="switch switch-custom block mbn taCenter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check_' . $this->id . '" name="field_types" class="legend-switch" ' . $active . ' onchange="changeStatusActive(' . $this->id . ', \'author\');"></input>
                <label data-off="' . Yii::t('app', 'Не') . '" data-on="' . Yii::t('app', 'Да') . '" for="check_' . $this->id . '"></label>
                <span></span>
            </label>';
    }

    public function getKartikImagesList() {
        $doctorImagesArr = array();
        $doctorImages = Author::find()->where('id = :id', [':id' => $this->id])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->one();
        if(isset($doctorImages->filename) and $doctorImages->filename!="" and $doctorImages->filename!=Null) {
            $fileName = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . "/authors/" . $doctorImages->filename;
            if (file_exists($fileName)) {
                $fileNameUrl = Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl . "/authors/thumb-270/" . $doctorImages->filename;
                $doctorImagesArr[] = Html::img($fileNameUrl, ['class' => 'file-preview-image', 'style' => 'width: 350px;']) .
                    '<a href="javascript://" onclick="deleteAuthorImage(' . $this->id . ')"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-bin"></span></a>';
            }
        }
        return $doctorImagesArr;
    }

    public function resizeImg($img) {
        $sz = getimagesize($img);
        $ratio = $sz[0] / $sz[1]; // w/h

        $w2 = Yii::$app->params['thumbswidth']; // thumb 1 width

        $image = new SimpleImage();

        $image->load($img);

        $image->resize($w2, round($w2 / $ratio));
        $image->save($img);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'active' => Yii::t('app','app.Active' ),
            'filename' => Yii::t('app','app.Filename' ),
            'sort' => Yii::t('app','app.Sort' ),
            'country_birth' => Yii::t('app','app.Birth Country' ),
            'names' => Yii::t('app','app.Names' ),
            'meta_desc' => Yii::t('app','app.Meta Desc' ),
            'filename' => Yii::t('app','app.Image' ),
            'birthday' => Yii::t('app','app.Birthday' ),
            'imageFiles' => Yii::t('app','app.Image' ),
            'description' => Yii::t('app','app.Review' ),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAuthorLangs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AuthorLang::className(), ['author_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

I didn't post the `_form.php` because it is the same for both actions (create and update) and I think that the problem is not in it.If you need it will update my question immediately. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason  it is possible that the update does not affect any row in the table. In this case the function return 0  .. for check this situation you should chek this this way

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#update()-detail

```
 if($model->update() !== false){
           var_dump(1);die;
       }else{
           var_dump($model->getErrors());die;// it dumps here but it returns an empty array
       }
```

then, just for debugging,  you could also try using  `$model->save(false)`  instead of `$model->update()` ... this way the $model is saved without regarding the validation  rules ..

Comment: Tried with the condition that you post and it goes in the `if` part. So it returns  1. Tried also with `$model->save(false)` but again nothing. I am really confused. How wrong it would be if hard code it? Like `Yii::$app->db->createCommand(query, [params])->execute()`.

Comment: this mean that no rows are involved  in update .. ?   . why ?   . are you sure you have not saved  the model (without change)  before .. ?   .. anyway  If you have no alternatives you can even try with the createCommand ... there is nothing wrong with it ... it's strange, however, that the update is not done.

Comment: Found it! Thank you very much for this line `are you sure you have not saved the model (without change) before` :D ! There really was another `$model->save()` before the `$model->update()`.